# Trouble with my While Loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Beginner in Java here and I'm creating a program that will calculate the area and volume of a sphere after a value for the radius has been given. If the radius is <= 0, then it should display an error message in the form of a JOptionPane and then return to asking for the radius, however, I am struggling with the while loop.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String volume = "V = (4(pi)r^3)/3";
    String area = "V = 4(pi)r^2";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Formulas for a Sphere:"+"\n"+"V = (4(pi)r^3)/3"+"\n"+"A = 4(pi)r^2");
    Double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Radius(cm)"));
    while(radius <= 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please insert a valid radius.");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, volume + " = " + Math.round((4*3.1415*Math.pow(radius,3)/3)) + "cm" + 
            "\n" + area + " = " + Math.round(4*3.1415*Math.pow(radius,2)));
```

Comment: You need to take the input _inside_ your loop. Otherwise, how will the loop ever end?

Answer (score 0):

The value of radius never changes in this loop

```
 while(radius <= 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please insert a valid radius.");
}
```

add this into the loop

```
 radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Radius(cm)"));
```

Comment: Aha! I was trying to do something similar, but kept accidentally trying to reinitiate the variable. Thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (just to avoid duplicating code):

```
while (true) {
    Double radius = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter  Radius(cm)"));
    if (radius > 0)
        break;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please insert a valid radius.");
}
```